# How to run db:migrate for test database in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, dbmigrate, test-environments

I created a new rails 5 app with postgresql db and modified the database.yml file. I successfully created both development and test databases, but when running migrations only development db is updated and test db remains intact.

Here's the list of commands i used:

```
rails db:create                     # Created both development and test
rails db:migrate                    # Migrated only to development
rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test     # Does nothing (no error output)
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test      # Same result as above
```

My database.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development
  username: myapp_admin
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 5432

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test
  username: myapp_admin
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

I also tried adding `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` to `test_helper.rb` but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got it to work by removing `host: localhost` from database.yml. Now `rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` works fine.